# How to change network adapter name via command line in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

Is there a way to change the network adapter name in batch or powershell script? possibly by specifying a connection number ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

Easy enough without PowerShell:

```
netsh interface set interface name="Old Name" newname="New Name"
```

Easy enough *with* PowerShell:

```
Get-NetAdapter -Name "Old Name" | Rename-NetAdapter -NewName "New Name"
```

Of course, in PS, you can also select your adapter by [whatever property you see fit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj130867.aspx).

```
Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceIndex 12 | Rename-NetAdapter -NewName "New Name"
```

Swiped from [Technet Blogs](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/01/14/renaming-network-adapters-by-using-powershell.aspx), which has a couple of other more complicated ways.

Comment: While PowerShell is only supported in Windows8+ AFAIK

Comment: @michelZ Powershell has been installed by default since Windows 7, and can be installed on OS as early as windows XP.

Comment: I'm refering to this article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj130867.aspx, saying that it is supported from Windows 8 / 2012 onwards. Just because you can install PowerShell does not mean that all commands work magically, I think

Comment: @MichelZ That article states that it is introduced in 4.0, which comes by default on server 2012 R2 and 8.1, but can also be installed on windows 7 and server 2008.

"Version 4.0 is integrated with Windows 8.1 and with Windows Server 2012 R2. Microsoft has also made PowerShell 4 available for Windows 7 SP1, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 and Windows Server 2012"

Comment: I'm speaking just about the Get-NetAdapter cmdlet by the way.. not PowerShell in general :)

Comment: It comes with WMF 4.0 (Windows Management Framework) which includes PowerShell 4.0, see [How to Install Windows PowerShell 4.0](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21016.how-to-install-windows-powershell-4-0.aspx)

Comment: I did install it, but I can't get Get-NetAdapter to work :)
`$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`
`4.0.-1,-1`
`Get-NetAdapter: The term 'get-netadapter' is not recognized [...]`

Comment: I suspect these cmdlets are only available on 8+/2012+, even if you do install PS 4.0. In case you're using an older OS, `netsh` or WMI (see the linked technet blogs article) should work.

Comment: -1 GetNetAdapter don't work on OS < Win 8

Comment: @Abhineet Good thing I gave another option that does work on ancient versions of Windows!

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Yes, but you should clearly declare in your solution that the Get-NetAdapter won't work on ancient versions of Windows.